# Speeding up loading a webpage into android using Jsoup

Tags: android, authentication, jsoup

I have created a app to fetch a table from a website into android using jsoup after logging into that site. Though it works fine it is very slow and takes a lot of time for the activity to start up. Can any one help me with this issue. I have attached the code below and thanks in advance

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extra!=null){
            Log.v("got", extra.getString("user")+extra.getString("pass"));
            user=extra.getString("user");
            pass=extra.getString("pass");
        }
        HomeList homelist=new HomeList(this);


        try {
            ArrayList<String> result=homelist.execute(user+pass).get();
            if(result.contains("rejected")){
                Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            else{
                tv.setText(user.toUpperCase(Locale.US));
                adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
                lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }


    }
    public class HomeList extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList<String>> {

        private  List<String> cookies;
        private HttpURLConnection conn;
        private final String USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36";
        private Home home;
         List<String> cook;
        private  int BUFF=50;
        String username;



             public HomeList(Home home) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                 this.home=home;
        }


            public HomeList() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }


            @Override


             protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    publishProgress("Loading");
                    String user=arg0[0].substring(0,10);
                    Log.v("user", user);
                    String pass=arg0[0].substring(10,arg0[0].length());
                    Log.v("pass", pass);
                    //int code=Integer.parseInt(arg0[0].substring(arg0[0].length()-1));
                    ArrayList<String> no=new ArrayList<String>();
                    no.add("rejected");

                    String url = "http://borealis.astra.edu.in";
                    //action url in form
                    String astra="http://borealis.astra.edu.in/index.php";
                    String attendance="http://borealis.astra.edu.in/index.php?option=com_base_attendancereport&Itemid=98";
                    HomeList coll=new HomeList();
                    //for cookies
                    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
                    //get form data to be sent
                    String page=coll.GetPageContent(url);
                    //collecting form data

                    String postParams = coll.getFormParams(page,user,pass);
                    System.out.println(postParams);
                    cook=cookies;
                    System.out.print(cook);
                    ArrayList<String> result=coll.sendPost(url,postParams);
                    if(result.contains("error"))
                        return no;
                    else
                    return result;
                    }


            private ArrayList<String> sendPost(String url, String postParams) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                URL obj;
                try {
                    obj = new URL(url);

                conn=(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "borealis.astra.edu.in");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
                for(String cookie:this.cookies){
                    conn.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie.split(";",1)[0]);
                    System.out.println(cookie);
                }
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(postParams);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(conn.getURL());
                System.out.println("posting data to "+url);
                System.out.println("parametrs are "+postParams);
                System.out.println("response Code "+responseCode);
                URL secondURL = new URL(conn.getHeaderField("Location"));
                conn=(HttpURLConnection) secondURL.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()),BUFF);
                Log.d("length", "got"+conn.getContentLength());
                System.out.println("redirected url" + conn.getURL());
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();
                while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null){
                    response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                Document doc=Jsoup.parse(response.toString());

                Elements table=doc.getElementsByClass("tiles_box");
                in.close();
                ArrayList<String> ele=new ArrayList<String>(); 
                if(table.first()!=null){

                    Iterator<Element> ite=table.select("tr").select("td").iterator();
                    ele.add(ite.next().text());
                    Log.d("td", ele.toString());
                    while(ite.hasNext()){
                        String td=ite.next().text();
                        if(!ele.contains(td)){
                            ele.add(td);
                            Log.d("td", ele.toString());
                            }
                    }
                    return ele;
                }

            else
            {
                ArrayList<String> error=new ArrayList<String>();
                error.add("error");
                return error;

            }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }




            private String getFormParams(String html, String user, String pass){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{

                System.out.println("extracting form data");
                Document doc=Jsoup.parse(html);
                Element form=doc.getElementById("form-login");
                Elements inputElements=form.getElementsByTag("input");
                List<String> paramsList=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(Element inputElement:inputElements){
                    String key=inputElement.attr("name");
                    String value=inputElement.attr("value");
                    if(key.equals("username"))
                        value=user;
                        if(key.equals("passwd"))
                            value=pass;
                            paramsList.add(key+"="+URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));
                }
                        StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
                        for(String param:paramsList){
                            if(result.length()==0){
                                result.append(param);
                            }else{
                                result.append("&"+param);
                            }
                        }
                        return result.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("error", e.toString());
                }
                return null;

            }

            private String GetPageContent(String url){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                URL obj=new URL(url);

                conn=(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(20);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setUseCaches(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "borealis.astra.edu.in");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");

                if(cookies!=null)
                    {
                    for(String cookie:this.cookies){

                    conn.addRequestProperty("cookie", cookie.split(";",1)[0]);
                }
                    }
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("sending get request "+url);
                System.out.println("response code is "+responseCode);
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()),BUFF);
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();
                while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null){



                    response.append(inputLine);


                }
                in.close();
                setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
                return response.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("error", e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            private void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.cookies=cookies;
                cook=cookies;
                System.out.print(cook);

            }
            public List<String> getCookies(){
                return cookies;
            }




            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line `ArrayList<String> result=homelist.execute(user+pass).get();` you lose all the advantages of multithreading. The problem is the `get()` method, which

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

In my opinion you should use a sort of callback, like this:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public interface OnWorkDone {
        public void doSomething(String s);
    }

    private OnWorkDone listener;

    public void setListener(OnWorkDone listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        //do something
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (listener != null) {
         listener.doSomething(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And, on the main class:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.setListener(new OnWorkDone() {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(String s) {
            //Use results
    }
});

task.execute(params);
```

Comment: can we use List as the argument of doSomething ??

Comment: You were right about the get() part, it was making the app slower. Though i didn't use the interface part i could make it work by removing the get(). Thank you :D

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer, if you think it solved your problem! ;)